# iterate of column in pandas and change value of cells - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a df with a column called 'postcodes'. These postcodes have spaces inbetween them. Is there a way to change the value of these cells (preferably without having to make a new csv) so that they dont have spaces (B91 2QD --> B912QD). Written below is the code i have so far, i know it doesnt happen but for the sake of the example, the last line would actually replace the values in the df.

```
df=pd.read_csv('foo')
pcode=df['postcode']
for i in pcode:
    i.replace(' ','')
```

Comment: you can ditch the loop and just do `df['postcode'] = df['postcode'].str.replace(' ','')`

Comment: @EdChum, cheers for the comment but it still doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work is not a complete problem description, post your raw data, code, desired output, the code you tried (including my suggestion) and the erroneous output that others can run so it can be reproduced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this to be helpful, either:

```
data[['A','B', 'C']] = data[['A','B', 'C']].str.replace("","")
```

Or for non_string data:

```
data[['A','B', 'C']] = data[['A','B', 'C']].replace(20,78)
```

This also works for multiple columns in a `dataframe`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe This will help you:

```
for i in range(len(pcode)-1):
    pcode[i] = pcode[i].replace(" ", "")
```